# How do I test the latest version of a skill that has been shared with me?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

The skill lives on someone else's amazon dev account.
I've been added as admin so that I have access to the skill.
I see build actions, code updates, model updates, etc. I can definitively see the latest changes on my web dev console.
However, when I try to test it, I interact with an older version of the skill. Same when I try to test it on my echo dot.

This skill is not in production.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you are logged in on the same account for your devices that you are using for Development.

You can double check in the Alexa mobile app under Skills & Games > Your Skills > (scroll right to) Dev and confirm that your skill you want to test is enabled on the account.